# .htaccess show 404 error if url has more than two slashes in html page

Tags: .htaccess

I have html page created from htaccess.

Like this.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(.*\.html) process/?category=$1&link=$2 [L]
```

It's working fine.

It redirects url

```
www.site.com/software/page.html
```

To

```
www.site.com/process/index.php?category=software&link=page.html
```

I want to show 404 error if url has more than two slashes.

For example

```
www.site.com/software/page.html/page.html
or
www.site.com/software/software/page.html
```

Should show 404 error instead of redirected like this.

```
www.site.com/process/index.php?category=software&link=page.html/page.html
```

Currently I am doing this with php but I want to do it in .htaccess so as to give 404 error on first request.

Please see and suggest any way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should run :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^[^/]*/[^/]*/ dhddhdhdhdhdh [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(.*\.html) process/?category=$1&link=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Its working but, all of my javascript and css are now disabled with this rule in .htaccess

Comment: I think this solution is working for all the page types like .js, .css etc

Comment: Ok. I understand. So i will edit my answer to fix this problem.

Comment: Can you answer my this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17653948/htaccess-pretty-url-lost-after-redirecting-non-www-to-www-urls)