# .htaccess - pretty url lost after redirecting non-www to www urls

Tags: .htaccess

I have made .htaccess 301 redirect to reirect non www to www, which is working fine but my pretty url is lost when a page is accessed with non www url.

I have done it this way.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.com [NC]
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(.*\.html) process/?category=$1&link=$2 [L]
```

It redirects url

```
http://www.site.com/software/page.html
```

To

```
http://www.site.com/process/index.php?category=software&link=page.html
```

Properly without loosing pretty url `www.site.com/software/page.html` in address bar.

It redirects url

```
http://site.com/software/page.html
```

To

```
http://www.site.com/process/index.php?category=software&link=page.html
```

Properly and now pretty url is lost and address in address bar is

```
http://www.site.com/process/index.php?category=software&link=page.html
```

Instead of

```
http://site.com/software/page.html
```

How to keep pretty url when page is accessed without www.

Please see and suggest any way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe problem is missing `L` flag in your first rule. Try this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.com$ [NC]
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^.]+\.html)$ /process/?category=$1&link=$2 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: What URL did you use to test this? And dump your complete .htaccess in your question.

Comment: I used non www url `http://site.com/software/page.html` working for  `http://www.site.com/software/page.html `

Comment: Your solution did work, I cleared my browser history and cookie now its working. The problem was missing `L` flag